# Jquery select all radiobuttons in a table where id's are name the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a checkbox that when clicked, should select all the radio buttons inside my table. Here is the code I have written sofar;

```
<script>
      $(":checkbox").click(function (e) {
        var radioClass = $(":radio").each(function(){
            if( $(this).hasClass($(':checkbox').attr('class')))
            {
                $(':radio').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
            }
        });
    });  
</script>
```

I have assigned the checkbox a class name of an array key. I have also assigned the radiobuttons with the same array key as their class name. When the checkbox is clicked,

I would like the code to search through all the radio buttons and get their class name. If the class name is the same as that of the checkbox, the radio button should be checked.

The code above just doesn't seem to work.

Here is my checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" id="{{ $customer->customer_id }}">
```

Here is my Radiobutton

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" id="{{ $customer->customer_id }}">
```

Comment: `if( $(this).hasClass($(':checkbox')` do you really have a class called `:checkbox?`

Comment: `:checkbox:` is a valid selector in jQuery https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/  his code is `if( $(this).hasClass($(':checkbox').attr('class')))` which is saying if the has a class that's equal to the entire `class` attribute on a checkbox

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML for this as well?  I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Marco the full statement is if( $(this).hasClass($(':checkbox').attr('class')))
if the radiobutton has the same class as the checkbox

Comment: @gerry I think the class array key, should be posted in your question so someone can assist.

Comment: @designtocode I have edited the code to include the checkbox and radiobutton code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
<script>
   $(".checkAll").click(function(e) 
   {
      var checkId = $(this).attr('id');
      if($(this).is(':checked'))
      {
         checkRadios(checkId);
      }
      else 
      {
         unCheckRadio(checkId);
      }
   });            
   function checkRadios(checkId) 
   {
      $(".radio").each(function(e)
      {
         var radId = $(this).attr('id');
         if($(this).attr('id') == checkId)
         {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
         }            
      });
   }
   function unCheckRadio(checkId) 
   {
      $(".radio").each(function(e)
      {
         var radId = $(this).attr('id');
         if($(this).attr('id') == checkId)
         {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
         }            
      });
   }
</script>
```